# android.media.Mediaplayer - Sounds to internal speakers only when Bluetooth-Headset is connected

Tags: android, bluetooth, media-player, alert

I wonder if it is possible to play sounds on the internal speakers of an Android-Device using android.media.MediaPlayer if a BlueTooth-Headset is connected.

Example: A user has paired his BlueTooth-Headset and my app running in the background wants to inform the user with some annoying sounds about an event. I don't want this sound to be played on the paired Bluetooth-Headset, but on the internal speakers of the Android device.

Is this possible using android.media.MediaPlayer? If yes, how?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at android.media.mediarouter?